# Filtered SharePoint 2013 library to OneDrive for business sync

Tags: office-365, sync, onedrive-for-business

We're currently syncing some SharePoint 2013 (online) libraries with OneDrive for business on user's machines which is all working great.

But, what we'd like to do is add a filter, specifically; only sync files that were uploaded to SharePoint within the last 7 days.

We're able to create a custom view for this on SharePoint but I can't see a way to sync to a view, only libraries. Am I asking for the impossible?

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive for Business typically synchronize everything in OneDrive ant it’s not possible (today) to filter sync.

Reference: [Sync one folder not entire OneDrive](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/251026.aspx)